# How should I analyse cyclic load times?

Tags: time-series

I'm in the process of analysing different PHP frameworks and part of this involves testing the load times. For this, I've programmed various usage scenario's. I'm however quite unsure on how to proceed from this.

I'm using Apache Benchmark to simulate the number of requests and the number of concurrent requests.

When I put the progression of the load times over time, I get the following chart:

[image]

As you can see, it's cyclic (I'm assuming the server clears a cache of sorts at one point, to drop the load times).

When I created a histogram, I got this:

[image]

From looking around here, that seems to resemble a Weibull-distribution. I'm however totally unfamiliar with that and looking into it as we speak.

I'm basically looking for a way that let's me compare different sets of similar data to find out which is the fastest. Ideally this would be a single value, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Since I haven't got that much experience with statistical analysis, I was hoping that one of the bright minds here might have the answer (or at least guide me in the right direction). If I've forgotten any information that might be useful, just let me know and I'll try to update as best as I can.